# Check to see if elements in a list have an SRC from a variable and then run code - jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I wish to check a variable called SRC against the source of images in a list from my HTML and if it returns true then run a certain function.

It seems that it is not currently running properly, please see the link for a live example.

http://jsbin.com/exigop/4/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the length property whenever you check for any element which is missing in your code.

```
if ($('ul li img[src=' + src + ']').length > 0) {
  //code here
}
```

Also you had few other issues in the code like using src as attribute selector which will not work because it cantains `/` and it is not escaped.

I have fixed those issues and also improvised the code. Take a look

Working **[demo](http://jsbin.com/exigop/6/edit)**

Comment: @Xavier - There were other issues as well which are fixed in the demo, take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute selectors need quotes around the attribute value.  You probably also want to check the count, not just the return value from the jQuery function:

```
if ($('ul li img[src="' + src + '"]').length > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have error in setTimeout, try

```
setTimeout(timeOut, 1000);
```

Comment: Actually, it's valid.  But since timeOut itself is a function, OP doesn't need to wrap it in an anonymous function: `setTimeout(timeOut, 1000);`